# Один контейнер накладывается на другой - начинает тормозить анимация. В чем может быть причина?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, transition

есть основное содержимое страницы, и есть не до конца выдвинутые при помощи transform: translate() за пределы страницы контейнеры.

при наведении на эту часть контейнера сбоку страницы, он плавно выдвигается (transition), при этом примерно на 1/3 заходит в пределы основного контента (обычные main, div, h и т.д.),
и с момента когда этот блок доходит до основного контента, продолжает двигаться с лагами.
Если отводить курсор до этого (выдвигать на 2/3) все плавно.

С чем это может быть связано и как решить проблему?

```css
.b1{
    background-image: url(img/sunnyBG.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    transform: translate(-77%);
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.wet1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 45%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.wet2{
    color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
.ha1{
    padding-left: 30px;
}
.button{
margin-top:50px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 55px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: 0.2s;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1; 
}
.button:hover{
    transform: translate(0);
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.main{
    position: absolute;
    top: 53%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:  translate(-50%, -50%);
    zoom: 1.1;
}

.wets{
    width: 800px;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.214);
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}
.main{
    position: absolute;
    top: 53%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:  translate(-50%, -50%);
    zoom: 1.1;
}

.wets{
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.214);
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    position: relative;
    /* border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); */
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<button class="button b1"><div class="wet11">
            <h2></h2> 
            <h1 class="ha1"></h1>
            <img class='img' src="img/sun-removebg-preview.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="wet22"> 
            <h3 style="margin: 0;"></h3>
          </div></button>
          
     <main class="main">
       <div class="wets">
       
     
     </div>
     
     </main>
```

Comment: Вам бы привести минимальный воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: в маленьком окне наведите на выглядывающий слева контейнер, когда он заходит на основной контейнер в центре, продолжает двигаться с сильными лагами в моем проекте

Comment: лично я никаких лагов не наблюдаю - всё плавно, туда и обратно

Comment: это просто пример кода. здесь все плавно, а в проекте увы